# SQL Server 2012 Transactional Replication Latency Warning Not Working

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have transactional replication setup on SQL Server 2012.  I have the default alerts setup and they're working with the exception of the alert for latency.  The alert for latency only fires when I have Replication Monitor open.  Is this by design?

Comment: This is by design. (I couldn't help myself)

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the job "Replication monitoring refresher for distribution" was disabled on the distributor.  I enabled the job and started it.  The alert appears to working correctly.

Comment: It looks like you may have two accounts; check [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for how to get them linked together.